# Twitter Bootstrap 3 menu issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a menu setup in a bootstrap template, which doesn't extend all the way to the right of the browser.

```html
<div class="row no-gutter featureMenu1">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8">

            <div id="navcontainerFeature1">
                <ul id="navlistFeature1">
                <li><a id="menu_0" class="feature1 feature1MenuActive">CURRENT PROJECTS</a></li>
                <li><a id="menu_1" class="feature1">PAST PROJECTS</a></li>
                <li><a id="menu_2" class="feature1">CUSTOM HOME BUILDING</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
```

```css
.featureMenu1 {
   background: #153586;
   width: 100%;
   height: 70px;
}

#navcontainerFeature1 ul
{
   margin-top: -10px;
   padding-left: 0;
   margin-left: 0;
   background-color: #153586;
   color: #859fd0;
}
```

You can see what I mean on the test site here, on the projects menu.  The two blue menu bars don't make it to the right side of the screen.

Comment: Add your background color to your `container-fluid` element instead of your `featureMenu1` element.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has a pull-right and pull-left class, that will take of that. I built a mock up for you here:

```
[1]: http://www.bootply.com/7qiDiqLeQb#


<!-- Static navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand pull-left" href="#">Project name</a>
          </div>


          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">CURRENT PROJECTS</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">PAST PROJECTS</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">CUSTOM HOME BUILDING</a></li>

            </ul>

          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->


        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
```